# required lightning-combobox does not will not validate

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-combobox

This is driving me absolutely batty - I have a required combobox in my LWC, and validation does not fire in navigating from field to field (as the lightning-input fields do) nor does it stop the save action from happening.

It worked briefly after I switched from pulling the option set from a Salesforce field to supplying them in a get statement, but then it stopped and hasn't worked since.

HTML

```
<table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr class="">
            <th scope="col">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Name"></div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Date">Date</div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Hours">Hours</div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Modality">Modality</div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Phone">Action</div>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <template for:each = {ERDHRecords} for:item = "ERDH" for:index="indexVar">
            <tr key={ERDH.Id} class="slds-hint-parent">
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <div class="slds-text-heading_small slds-text-align_center">
                            <c-row-number-comp index={indexVar}></c-row-number-comp>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div  >
                        <lightning-input data-id={ERDH.Id} required="true" type="date" name="date" label="Date" value={ERDH.Date__c} max={todaysDate} variant="label-hidden" onchange={handleDateChange}></lightning-input>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td >
                    <div>
                        <lightning-input data-id={ERDH.Id} required="true" type="number"  formatter="decimal" step="any" name="hours" label="Hours" max="16" value={ERDH.Hours__c} variant="label-hidden" onchange={handleHoursChange}></lightning-input>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <lightning-combobox data-id={ERDH.Id} name="modality"  label="Modality" value={ERDH.Modality__c} variant="label-hidden" onchange={handleModalityChange} options={modalityOptions} required="true"> 
                        </lightning-combobox>
                       
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a name={indexVar} data-id={ERDH.Id} onclick={removeRow}>
                            <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:delete" alternative-text="delete" label="delete row" variant="label-hidden" size="small"></lightning-icon>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </template>
        <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
            <td >
                
            </td>
            <td >
                <div   style="text-align: right;">
                    Total Hours:
                </div>
            </td>
            <td >
                <div   style="padding-left: 12px;">
                    {totalHours}
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div style="text-align: right; font-weight: bold; color: red;">
                    <template lwc:if={saveMessage}>You have unsaved entries.<br/>Please save before clicking Next.</template>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                    <lightning-button 
                    label={toggleSaveLabel} 
                    icon-name="utility:save" 
                    slot="actions"
                    onclick={handleSave}>
                </lightning-button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

===== JS =====

```
import { LightningElement,track, api} from 'lwc';
import {FlowAttributeChangeEvent} from 'lightning/flowSupport';

import getRecords from '@salesforce/apex/CoachPortalHelperClassesEYD.getERDH';
import insertERDH from '@salesforce/apex/CoachPortalHelperClassesEYD.addERDH';
import Date_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Engagement_Report_Date_and_Hours__c.Date__c';
import Hours_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Engagement_Report_Date_and_Hours__c.Hours__c';
import Modality_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Engagement_Report_Date_and_Hours__c.Modality__c';
import RecordID_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Engagement_Report_Date_and_Hours__c.id';

export default class EngagementReportHoursEntry2 extends LightningElement {
    @api ERid;
    @api ERDHList;
    @track ERDHRecord = {Id: RecordID_FIELD, Date__c : Date_FIELD, Hours__c : Hours_FIELD,Modality__c : Modality_FIELD};
    @track ERDHRecords = [{Date__c : Date_FIELD, Hours__c : Hours_FIELD, Modality__c:Modality_FIELD, Id : 'New'+Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 16)}];
    @track saveMessage = false;
    @track totalHours = 0;
    toggleSaveLabel = 'Save';    

   @api
   validate() {
     if(this.saveMessage) {
       return {
         isValid: false,
         errorMessage: 'Please click the Save button to save your time entries before proceeding'
       };
       }
     else {
       return { isValid: true };
     }
   }

   @api connectedCallback(){
    if(this.ERDHList)
        this.ERDHRecords = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.ERDHList));
        this.sumHours();
    }

    @api disconnectedCallback(){
            console.log(' disconnected callback ' +  JSON.stringify(this.ERDHRecords));
            this.dispatchEvent(new FlowAttributeChangeEvent('ERDHList', this.ERDHRecords));
        }
    

    addRow(){
        
        this.ERDHRecords.push( {Date__c : Date_FIELD, Hours__c : Hours_FIELD, Modality__c:Modality_FIELD, Id : 'New'+Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 16)});
    }

    removeRow(event){
        const indexPos = event.currentTarget.name;
        let remList = [];
        remList = this.ERDHRecords;
        remList.splice(indexPos,1);
        this.ERDHRecords = remList;
        this.sumHours();
        this.handleChange();
    }

    handleDateChange(event){
        let foundelement = this.ERDHRecords.find(ele => ele.Id == event.target.dataset.id);
        foundelement.Date__c = event.target.value;
        this.ERDHRecords = [...this.ERDHRecords];
        this.saveMessage = true;
        this.handleChange();
        
    }

    get todaysDate() {
        var today = new Date();
        var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
        var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
        var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
        today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' +  dd;
        return today
    }

    get modalityOptions() {
        return [
                 { label: 'In-person', value: 'In-person' },
                 { label: 'Virtual', value: 'Virtual' },
               ];
    }

    handleHoursChange(event){
        let foundelement = this.ERDHRecords.find(ele => ele.Id == event.target.dataset.id);
        foundelement.Hours__c = event.target.value;
        this.ERDHRecords = [...this.ERDHRecords];
        this.saveMessage = true;
        this.sumHours();
        this.handleChange();
        //console.log(' ==> ' +  JSON.stringify(this.ERDHRecords));
    }

    handleModalityChange(event){
        let foundelement = this.ERDHRecords.find(ele => ele.Id == event.target.dataset.id);
        foundelement.Modality__c = event.target.value;
        this.ERDHRecords = [...this.ERDHRecords];
        this.saveMessage = true;
        this.handleChange();
        //console.log(' ==> ' +  JSON.stringify(this.ERDHRecords));
    }

    sumHours(){
        let sum = 0;
        this.ERDHRecords.forEach((ERDH) => {
            if(!isNaN(ERDH.Hours__c)) {
                sum += parseFloat(ERDH.Hours__c);
            }
          });
          this.totalHours = sum;
    }
    handleChange(){
        const attributeChangeEvent = new FlowAttributeChangeEvent(
            'ERDHList',
            this.ERDHRecords
        );
        this.dispatchEvent(attributeChangeEvent);
    }
    
    handleSave(){

        //console.log(' ==> ' +  JSON.stringify(this.ERDHRecords));

        const isInputsCorrect = [...this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input,lightning-combobox')]
            .reduce((validSoFar, inputField) => {
                inputField.reportValidity();
                return validSoFar && inputField.checkValidity();
            }, true);

        this.handleChange();
        if (isInputsCorrect) {
            this.toggleSaveLabel = 'Saving...';
            var toSaveList = [];
            this.ERDHRecords.forEach((element) => {
                let ERDH = { 'sobjectType': 'Engagement_Report_Date_and_Hours__c' };
                ERDH.Id = element.Id.substring(0,3)=='a7V'? element.Id : null;
                ERDH.Date__c = element.Date__c;
                ERDH.Hours__c = element.Hours__c;
                ERDH.Modality__c = element.Modality__c;
                console.log(ERDH);
                toSaveList.push(ERDH);
            })

            console.log(toSaveList);
            insertERDH({ERDHList : toSaveList,ERid: this.ERid})
            .then(() => {
                this.toggleSaveLabel = 'Saved';
                this.saveMessage = false;
                console.log('Success Log');
                this.error = undefined;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.error = error;
                this.record = undefined;
                console.log("Error in Save call back:", this.error);
            })
            .finally(() => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.toggleSaveLabel = 'Save';
                }, 3000);
            });
        }
    }
    
 
}
```